# Updating field validates password?

Tags: php, mysqli, password-hash

Okay, so as a side project for my education, I'm currently working on a secure login system using PHP and mysqli. It's been going smoothly, but now I encountered an issue my peers, teachers and I are baffled by.

I'm hashing and checking my passwords via password_hash and password_verify.

When I create an account, everything gets stored in the database correctly. Then, when I try to login, using the correct password, it's giving me an error that my password isn't corect.

Now here's the kicker: When I go into PHPMyAdmin, copy the hashed password stored in the database, and update the password field with that excact copied password... it works. I can login as intended, with the password I used, and it won't give me any errors.

Does anyone have an idea what's up, and how to fix it?

Code used for registering:

```
public function createAccount()
{
    global $con;

    $this->password = password_hash($this->password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT)."\n";
    $sql='INSERT into user (username, password, email, creation_date)
        VALUES (?,?,?,?)';

    // Prepare statement
    $stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
    if($stmt === false) {
      trigger_error('Wrong SQL: ' . $sql . ' Error: ' . $con->error, E_USER_ERROR);
    }

    // Bind parameters. Types: s = string, i = integer, d = double,  b = blob
    $stmt->bind_param('ssss',$this->username,$this->password,$this->email,$this->creationDate);

    // Execute statement
    $stmt->execute();

    echo $stmt->insert_id;
    echo $stmt->affected_rows;

    $stmt->close();

    $_SESSION['login'] = true;
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    Header("Location: index.php");
}
```

Code used for validating credentials:

```
public function fetchCredentials() {
    // Select a set of credentials from the username given in form and return as array
    global $con;
    $sql = 'SELECT id, password FROM user WHERE username = ?';

    // Prepare statement 
    $stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
    if($stmt === false) {
      trigger_error('Wrong SQL: ' . $sql . ' Error: ' . $con->error, E_USER_ERROR);
    }

    // Bind parameters. Types: s = string, i = integer, d = double,  b = blob
    $stmt->bind_param('s',$this->username);

    // Execute statement
    $stmt->execute();

    // Store all results in an array
    $rs=$stmt->get_result();
    $arr = $rs->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $stmt->close();

    return($arr);
}

public function validateCredentials() {
    // Get credentials
    $arr = $this->fetchCredentials();

    // Validate username
    if (count($arr) > 1) {
        $this->error = 'crit';
        $this->abort = true;
    } else if (count($arr) < 1) {
        $this->error = 'badLogin';
        $this->abort = true;
    } else {
        $arr = $arr[0];
    }

    echo $arr['password'].'<br>'.$this->password;
    // Validate password. NOTE: This is where the issue arises. Password_verify() will return false where it    should return true.
    if ($this->abort == false && !password_verify($this->password, $arr['password'])) {
        $this->error = 'badLogin';
        $this->abort = true;
    }

    // Return values if needed
    if ($this->abort == false) {
        $this->id = $arr['id'];
    }
    return $this->abort;
}
```

Part that calls the logging in: (Yes, the validatecredentials function is getting called twice. Yes, there are some other things in there that aren't very well-written. This part of the code still needs some work and it's the first thing I'll do after fixing the issue above)

```
function login()
{
    $newCred = new credentials(
    $_POST['username'],
    $_POST['password']);

    if ($newCred->checkForm() == false
    && $newCred->validateCredentials() == false) {
        $newLogin = new login(
        $newCred->validateCredentials()['id']);

        $newLogin->login();
        $newLogin->getUserDetails();
    } else {
        $newCred->fetchError();
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you think someone can help you without a single line of your code?

Comment: Code pls. however from experience of hashes not allowing logins properly make sure your DB Table column is set to text or some large number thats not going to cut off the hash

Comment: Your post started badly from the beginning... you are using mysqli instead of PDO... What type of hash are you using? and also, please provide a code sample to know what you are dealing with!

Comment: @Typhomism the column is set to a varchar(255), so that should be fine.

Comment: @RikPronk if you print the hashed value to the screen right before saving it then check that against what is saved are they the same?

Comment: @micheal I'll get a code sample yeah, I should have done that.

Comment: @Typhomism Oh, good idea, I'll do that. I didn't actually think about that yet.

Comment: @Typhomism Yeah, that will print the same value.

Comment: How is the `validateCredentials()` function being called? Or, is it not being called?

Comment: @Fred-ii- Added that chunk in. Yeah, it's not the best, validateCredentials() is actually being called twice if the credentials are correct, I have some work to do on that. However, since it works after updating the password field, it does actually function.

Comment: What about the form itself, are both form elements named and no typos? Using correct method etc. Are you checking for errors? Doesn't seem like you are.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yes. Actually, all of this code works correctly, but only after updating the password field in the database with the exact same value that's aleady put in there by the code.

Comment: @RikPronk An advice to a fellow developer: This is the kind of problem that's very common and very easily solved by using a debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, to everyone who helped: Thanks. I was just helped by my classmate and he managed to find the problem. I am hitting myself right now.

```
$this->password = password_hash($this->password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT)."\n";
```

Here it is. "\n". A newline. I grabbed my code from an example, and that was in there for some reason. When I updated the database, the newline got deleted.